# In Ghidra can I have two binaries loaded into tabs and create a new struct that I can use in both?

Tags: ghidra

I'm using Ghidra to work out the structure of some binary files. No code.

I can use the Structure Editor to define a struct, such as the header of the file format.

But I can only find a way to create the struct in the context of one of the files and then it will not be visible to the other.

Is there a way to make it visible to both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have two PNG files open in tabs
[image: Ghidra Listing panel with two tabs]

Now on the bottom right in Data Type Manager I create a new archive file `foo.gdt`

Click the small black arrow -> New File Archive

[image: Ghidra Structure Editor]

In that `.gdt` archive I create an arbitrary structure with three `dword`s named
`pngheader`, `pngtail`, `pngfeet`

[image: Ghidra Data Type Manager]

Now I can apply this structure to both files
using data->choose data type
(press <kbd>T</kbd> shortcut) as below

[image: Ghidra Listing window with new struct applied]

Are you looking for this?

Answer (score 2):

Programs in the same project can share data types through the data type manager of each program.  This can be done using drag-n-drop from one data type manager to the other or through copy (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) with focus on the type and paste (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> ) with focus on the directory or top level archive where the data type should be copied to.